# how to set directory permissions of windows server 2012 so Visual Basic 2015 windows app ‘kill’ doesn’t get file permission error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis, smtp, file-permissions

I have a Visual Basic windows app that reads incoming SMTP email files from c:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\ and then moves them renamed to c:\primary\ .

I’ve set Windows file permissions of both directories c:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\ and c:\primary\ to “everyone” full access.

I have a 2nd VB.NET windows app that reads each file, processes it, then deletes it using ‘kill(filepath)’ which gets the error:
“An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Access to the path '\\C\Primary\9255551212@vzwpix.com #71615 1.TXT' is denied.”
The file’s property > Security has “everyone” full access.

How do I set file permissions for the directories to prevent this error and be safe from hacker attack and not use “everyone” permission?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:   Changed \\C  to just "C:".